# Set a Toggle Switch in Settings Bundle to hide & show buttons

Tags: xcode, uibutton, nsuserdefaults, uiswitch, settings.bundle

I Currently have a UISwitch that using an "if" statement hides or unhides some UIButtons. Than the ON/OFF state of the switch and the Hidden state of the Buttons are saved in NSUserDefaults. I want to know how to make that switch appear in the Settings Bundle.

Here is "if" statement code in .m:

```
- (IBAction)switchTheSwitch:(id)sender {
if (Languages.on) {
    china.hidden = NO;
    japan.hidden = NO;
    french.hidden = NO;
    spanish.hidden = NO;
}

else {
    china.hidden = YES;
    japan.hidden = YES;
    french.hidden = YES;
    spanish.hidden = YES;

}
[self buttonHidden:sender];
}
```

Now here is my code that saves the hidden state of the switch in .m:

```
- (void)buttonHidden:(id)sender {

NSUserDefaults *Defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[Defaults setBool:china.hidden forKey:ChinaChanged];
[Defaults setBool:japan.hidden forKey:JapanChanged];
[Defaults setBool:french.hidden forKey:FrenchChanged];
[Defaults setBool:spanish.hidden forKey:SpanishChanged];
[Defaults synchronize];

}
```

And here is my code for saving the ON/OFF state in .m:

```
- (IBAction)switchChangedValue:(id)sender {
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults setBool:Languages.on forKey:SwitchChanged];
[userDefaults synchronize];

}
```

Here is my view did load:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

NSUserDefaults *Defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
china.hidden = [Defaults boolForKey:ChinaChanged];
japan.hidden = [Defaults boolForKey:JapanChanged];
french.hidden = [Defaults boolForKey:FrenchChanged];
spanish.hidden = [Defaults boolForKey:SpanishChanged];

[super viewDidLoad];


NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
Languages.on = [userDefaults boolForKey:SwitchChanged];

}
```

How do I make a Toggle Switch in a Settings Bundle replace a switch on the View Controller?